# Redirect stdout from loaded dll

Tags: redirect, dll, pipe, stdout, crt

I have an application that redirects its own stdout to a pipe (using dup & dup2).
In a separate thread I capture everything that's written to the pipe.

Unfortunately, this does not work for any output printed in DLL's that are loaded by the application.
I've learned this is due to each module having it's own copy of the CRT (I'm compiling /MT), and thus it's own stdout/stderr variables.

How can I modify the stdout/stderr in loaded modules to also redirect to my pipe?